# Создание корпуса из двух

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Допустим у меня есть два корпуса текстов (один скорее даже не корпус, а набор коротких фраз) на две разные темы и я хочу как бы скрестить эти два корпуса и получить корпус, где эти темы в каждом документе будут встречаться, как я сейчас делаю: Я беру длинный корпус, каждый документ разбираю по словам на их части речи (существительное, глагол, ...) и заменяю на слово с такой же частью речи из другого корпуса, получается часто очень несвязные тексты, но оно и понятно, как можно сделать лучше, чтобы учитывать смысл между словами? (желательно то, что легко завести с пол тычка)

Comment: А в чём смысл сего действа? По-хорошему надо учить модель по очереди на обоих корпусах просто, да и всё. И вообще смотря, что за задача стоит.

Comment: Задача стоит генерации текстов по смешанной тематике. Нельзя обучить на первом, он слишком маленький (где короткие фразы).

Comment: А нет вариантов. Big Data потому так и называется, что вам нужно очень много данных, чтобы обучить модель. Настоящих данных. Генерируя искусственные данные вы научите модель искусственным примерам. С картинками это ещё как-то работает в силу того, что картинки могут приходить искажёнными и это хороший метод, а с текстами так не работает.

Comment: спросите в https://t.me/natural_language_processing